# Cant seem to change height the Icon element in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

i have been trying to use tailwind with nextjs.

I am unable to give any other height to my HomeIcon element from heroicons other than h-5.
if i try to give it any other height it fills all the screen.

```
<div >
   <HomeIcon className='w-5 h-9'/>
</div>
```

the above code occupies the Whole screen.

```
<div >
   <HomeIcon className='w-5 h-5'/>
</div>
```

works fine

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: @ViniciusCainelli added some code

Comment: try adding that icon in a div and give the div a fixed height

Answer (score 3):

If you want to give the element the desired `height`, set the `width` to the same value and it should work.
Of course, the `context` in which you embed the icons is also **super important**. In addition, read about the height property in [tailwindcss](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height) and [heroicons](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/heroicons) These icons have some `limitations` that you need to be **aware** of when using them correctly.

[image]

---

Try this:

```
<HomeIcon className="h-20 w-20" />
```

---

My example code:

```
import { HomeIcon } from "@heroicons/react/solid";

function icons() {
  return (
    <div className="flex items-center justify-center gap-10 h-screen">
      <div className="">
        <HomeIcon className="h-6 w-6" />
        <small>height 6</small>
      </div>
      <div className="">
        <HomeIcon className="h-10 w-10" />
        <small>height 10</small>
      </div>
      <div className="">
        <HomeIcon className="h-12 w-12" />
        <small>height 12</small>
      </div>
      <div className="">
        <HomeIcon className="h-14 w-14" />
        <small>height 14</small>
      </div>
      <div className="">
        <HomeIcon className="h-16 w-16" />
        <small>height 16</small>
      </div>
      <div className="">
        <HomeIcon className="h-20 w-20" />
        <small>height 20</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default icons;
```

---

Output:

[image]

*Tested:  "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.2","@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.2.1","next": "11.0.1","react": "17.0.2"*

Comment: so we should only use 6,10,12,14,20?

Comment: @Akhilgavvala These were values for example...you can use other values .. however there are some limitations as mentioned above ;-)

Comment: @Akhilgavvala  Did the answers solve your problem?

Comment: it did to some extent but it keeps breaking from time to time

Answer (score 1):

I also just had this issue and my problem was that i miss spelt the "components" directory and tailwind.config.js wasn't picking it up

tailwind.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```